# RegEx match rational literals with decimals except incomplete rational literals

Tags: javascript, regex

To match numbers like `-3+-1.5/45,32`, I'm trying to write a Regular Expression, and I'm very close to what I need.

I have the following (JavaScript) regular expression to match decimal numbers in a certain format:

```
(   // 1st alternative:
(   [+-]?   // an optional unary +-
    [\d_]*  // 0-9 and _ digit separator any number of times
    [,.]?   // one of these decimal separators, once
    [\d]+   // 0-9 at least once
)
|   // 2nd alternative
(   [+-]?   // an optional unary +-
    [\d_]+  // 0-9 and _ digit separator, at least once
    [,.]?   // one of these decimal separators, once
    [\d]*   // 0-9 any number of times
)
)
```

That is, the previous matches `10_00_0000.90`, `1_00,99`,  `0.9`, `9,` and `.9` but *not* `.` or `,`.

Next, I experimented with this regex to match rational number expressions using the regex mentioned above.

```
([+-]?[\d_]*[+-]?(([+-]?[\d_]*[,.]?[\d]+)|([+-]?[\d_]+[,.]?[\d]*))\/(([+-]?[\d_]*[,.]?[\d]*)|([+-]?[\d_]+[,.]?[\d]*)))
```

It works like:

```
(
[+-]?  // optional unary +-
[\d_]* // optional 0-9 and _ digit separator (for compound numbers)
[+-]?  // optional infix +- for 2+3/2 OR 2-2/3
(   // begin the regex from above, for before the / numer / denom separator
    (       // all as above
    [+-]?   // this is intentional: the numerator itself may be signed
    [\d_]*
    [,.]?
    [\d]+
    )
    |
    (
    [+-]?
    [\d_]+
    [,.]?
    [\d]*
    )
)
\/         // numerator / denominator separator
(([+-]?[\d_]*[,.]?[\d]*)|([+-]?[\d_]+[,.]?[\d]*))) // same as above
```

You can find the regex and a couple of tests here (click "unit tests" on the left, then click the play button): https://regex101.com/r/bB8eO2/5

So you don't have to click, here are my tests:

```
/5          assert that regex   does not match              PASS
4/5         assert that capture group 1 equals  4/5         PASS
-1/3        assert that capture group 1 equals  -1/3        PASS
3/-8        assert that capture group 1 equals  3/-8        PASS
+4.12/-.90  assert that capture group 1 equals  +4.12/-.90  PASS
+1-6/7.     assert that capture group 1 equals  +1-6/7.     PASS
1-+6/7      assert that capture group 1 equals  1-+6/7      PASS
-1+-.4/5.   assert capture group 1 equals       -1+-.4/5.   PASS
-1+-.4/     assert regex does not match                     FAIL
```

Everything works properly except that one last failing test. I've fiddled with the quantifiers in the denominator, and I can get the last test to pass, but then trailing decimal separators `[.,]` are left out and the second-to-last and first test fail: https://regex101.com/r/mQ9mN8/1

This is for a lexer, so it would be nice to use a regex and not *yet* a proper parser to just test: is this thing a number, or is it an identifier?

Comment: I see that the last value [is not matched](https://regex101.com/r/mQ9mN8/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The tests I copied to the question are from the *first* link not the *second*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://regex101.com/r/bB8eO2/6

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The problem is that when I get the last one to not match, then some other values match or don't that should/n't

Comment: Ok, I see: the alternation  group 1st branch wins, and the 2nd one that matches `4.`-like values has no chance to match, right? That is why you replace `+` with `*` in `[+-]?[\d_]*[,.]?[\d]+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly.

Comment: Try [`([+-]?[\d_]*[+-]?(?:[+-]?(?:[\d_]+(?:[,.]\d*)?|[.,]\d+))\/(?:[+-]?(?:[\d_]+(?:[,.]\d*)?|[.,]\d+)))`](https://regex101.com/r/bB8eO2/7).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, excellent, thank you! make that an answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
([+-]?[\d_]*[+-]?(?:[+-]?(?:[\d_]+(?:[,.]\d*)?|[.,]\d+))\/(?:[+-]?(?:[\d_]+(?:‌​[,.]\d*)?|[.,]\d+)))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB8eO2/7)

Pattern breakdown:

```
(
 [+-]?[\d_]*[+-]?   # Optional + or - followed with 0+ digits or underscore and again optional - or +
 (?:[+-]?           # optional - or +
  (?:[\d_]+         # 1+ digits or underscore
   (?:[,.]\d*)?     # Optional sequence of a . or , followed with 0+ digits
   |                # or
   [.,]\d+          # , or , followed with 1+ digits
  )
 )
 \/
 (?:[+-]?           # optional - or +
  (?:[\d_]+         # 1+ digits or underscore
   (?:‌​[,.]\d*)?     # Optional sequence of a . or , followed with 0+ digits
   |                # or
   [.,]\d+          # , or , followed with 1+ digits
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: I've decided to go with this instead :D [`/^((?:[+-]?(?:[\d][\d_]*[\d]|[\d])(?:e[+-]?[+-]?[\d_]+)?[YZEPTGMKHDdcmμnpfazy]*)?[+-]?(?:[+-]?(?:\d[\d_]*\d[,.]\d*|\d+[,.]|[.,]\d+|\d+[,.]\d+)(?:e[+-]?[+-]?(?:\d[\d_]*\d|\d))?[YZEPTGMKHDdcmμnpfazy]*|[+-]?(?:[\d][\d_]*[\d]|[\d])(?:e[+-]?[+-]?[\d_]+)?[YZEPTGMKHDdcmμnpfazy]*)\/(?:[+-]?(?:\d[\d_]*\d[,.]\d*|\d+[,.]|[.,]\d+|\d+[,.]\d+)(?:e[+-]?[+-]?(?:\d[\d_]*\d|\d))?[YZEPTGMKHDdcmμnpfazy]*|[+-]?(?:[\d][\d_]*[\d]|[\d])(?:e[+-]?[+-]?[\d_]+)?[YZEPTGMKHDdcmμnpfazy]*))$/`](https://regex101.com/r/gR3uO2/4)